# Comparing Excel files in TFS

Tags: excel, tfs, ms-office, office365

Has anybody managed to successfully integrate Microsoft Office Spreadsheet Compare into Microsoft TFS for comparing different versions of an Excel file?

I was able to define Spreadsheet Compare as alternative diff tool but whenever I try to compare two changesets of an Excel file, Spreadsheet Compare opens but crashes immediately.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winmerge with its [xDocDiff](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiffPlugin/en/index.html) plugin lets you compare Excel and Word files.

This [blog](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/) tells you how to setup Visual Studio for using WinMerge for compare.

You could simply enable xdocdiff plugin in WinMerge. This way, you will also be able to use all file types that xdocdiff supports.

If you insist on using SpreadSheets Compare in TFS, you could take a look at this tutorial: [**VSTS Compare Excel Spread Sheets**](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2018/01/05/VSTS-Compare-Excel-Spread-Sheets.aspx)

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.